# How to report list data to file excel?

Tags: java, spring, export-to-csv

I using restfull service and I want to export data to file excel.
I have class ReportExcel : to format file excel.

```
public class ReportExcel {
public static ByteArrayInputStream tasksToExcel(List<ReportTaskToTimeResponse> allTasks) throws IOException {
    String[] COLUMNs = { "Task", "User Name", "Project Name", "Hours" };
    try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ) {
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Report");

        Font headerFont = workbook.createFont();
        headerFont.setBold(true);
        headerFont.setColor(IndexedColors.BLUE.getIndex());

        CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        headerCellStyle.setFont(headerFont);

        // Row for Header
        Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);

        // Header
        for (int col = 0; col < COLUMNs.length; col++) {
            Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
            cell.setCellValue(COLUMNs[col]);
            cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
        }

        int rowIdx = 1;
        for (ReportTaskToTimeResponse reportTaskToTimeResponse : allTasks) {
            Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIdx++);

            row.createCell(0).setCellValue(reportTaskToTimeResponse.getTask());
            row.createCell(1).setCellValue(reportTaskToTimeResponse.getUserName());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(reportTaskToTimeResponse.getProjectName());
            row.createCell(2).setCellValue(reportTaskToTimeResponse.getHours());
        }

        workbook.write(out);
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
    }
}
```

}

this is Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/reports/tasks/allTasks.xlsx", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/csv")
public ResponseEntity<?> reportExcelTasks(@RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate, @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate) throws IOException{

    LocalDateTime startDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(fromDate);
    LocalDateTime endDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(toDate);

    List<ReportTaskToTimeResponse> list = reportService.getTaskOfMemberToTime(startDate, endDate);

    ByteArrayInputStream in = ReportExcel.tasksToExcel(list);

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=allTasks.xlsx");

    return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(in));
}
```

But when I call to this api so it don't active, and postman return for me:

```
PK�H<N_rels/.rels���j�0�_���8�`�Q��2�m��4[ILb��ږ���.[K
```

�($}��v?�I�Q.���uӂ�h���x>=��@��p�H"�~�}�   �n����*"�H�׺؁�����8�Z�^'�#��7m{��O�3���G�u�ܓ�'��y|a�����D�    ����l_EYȾ�����vql3�ML��eh���*����\3�Y0���oJ׏�    :��^���}PK��z��IPK�H6�PU�C���{�X�%����]8�R�
q�cfgfW�d�q�ZCB|��|��*h㻆},^�{Va�^K<4�6�N�XQ�ǆ�9�!P��$��҆�d�c�D�j);��ѝP�g���E�M'O�ʕ�����H7L�h���R���G��^�'�{���zސʮB��3�˙��h.�h�W�жF�j娄CQՠ똈���}ιL�U:D�����%އ����,�B����[�    �� ;˱� �{N��~��X��p�ykOL��kN�V����ܿBZ~����q�� �ar��{O�PKz��q;PK�H��$;�SC
;̢(�ra�g�l�&�e��L!y�%��49��`_���4G���F��J��Wg ...

Comment: Call this from browser or application instead of postman.

Comment: I tried on the client but the result is still the same

Comment: It is probably trying to render the response instead of downloading it.

Comment: everyone can refer in here : https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-boot/excel-file-download-from-springboot-restapi-apache-poi-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently all your operation are done in memory, which will be problematic in case of large file. Try to save file somewhere on server and then write to `ServletResponse`. Please use below sample code to download the excel file as attachment.

```
private static final String FILENAME = "fileName.xls";


@PostMapping(value = "/reports/tasks/allTasks.xlsx", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public void reportExcelTasks(@RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate, @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

LocalDateTime startDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(fromDate);
LocalDateTime endDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(toDate);

List<ReportTaskToTimeResponse> list = reportService.getTaskOfMemberToTime(startDate, endDate);

    ByteArrayInputStream in = ReportExcel.tasksToExcel(list);
    IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(FILENAME, "UTF-8"));
    response.flushBuffer();
}
```

If you want to test the output try below sample html code to post action.

```
<html>
 <body>
   <form method = "post" action="http://localhost:8080/reports/tasks/allTasks.xlsx">    
      <input type = "text" name = "fromDate" required/>
      <input type = "text" name = "toDate" required/>
      <input type = "submit"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Try to open this file in browser and add the required fields. This should download the file in your local with the all the data.

Comment: so sad! It not ok! The result is same my question

Comment: @NguyễnThành are you trying to render the excel in page or download? because it should download the file as per above code.

Comment: yes, It is download, so Front-end can't read file because It is excel file, I tested and done.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static final String COMPANY_ACCOUNT_FILENAME_EXCEL_EXPORT = "your FileName.xls";

@RequestMapping(value = "/reports/tasks/allTasks.xlsx", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/csv")
public void reportExcelTasks(HttpServletResponse response,
@RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate, @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate) throws IOException{

    LocalDateTime startDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(fromDate);
    LocalDateTime endDate = DateTimeUtils.convertStringToLocalDateTime(toDate);

    List<ReportTaskToTimeResponse> list = reportService.getTaskOfMemberToTime(startDate, endDate);

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = ReportExcel.tasksToExcel(list);
    String fileName = COMPANY_ACCOUNT_FILENAME_EXCEL_EXPORT;

    response.setContentType("application/x-download");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"));
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
}
```

please update the following code:

```
 workbook.write(out);
 return new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

to be:

```
return workbook;
```

Comment: I don't understand "workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());" and system still don't understand

Comment: Output in stream，you can test it in browser,don't use postman please. browser can   download it directly.

Comment: I have used it,I invoked your result list,list have already worked to create workbook,all your data is there.I edited it.

Comment: when I run, system notify "Cannot write data, document seems to have been closed already" ?

Comment: as you see, the return value type is void, write method consumed stream, so you can't return nothing. stream is closed.

Comment: It just can try by browse?

Comment: but I using restfull service

Comment: of course not, in browse just make sure your code is OK.export excel need front-end development engineer debugging it.

Comment: That's not true @wanwan, you can not call that from a browser since it's a POST method, but you can use a rest client (like curl, Postman, etc.). You don't need a full frontend application to call REST APIs

Comment: @wanwan I can't write in response!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
public class FileResponse<T> {
    private final T file;
    private final String fileName;

    public FileResponse(T file, String fileName) {
        this.file = file;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
Workbook workbook = yourService.createExcel(); // call tasksToExcel here
FileResponse<Workbook> excel = new FileResponse<>(workbook, "yourfilename.xlsx");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
excel.getFile().write(outputStream);

return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"))
    .contentLength(outputStream.size()) // so web browsers will know the size of your file, this is just a nice-to-have feature
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + excel.getFileName())
    .body(outputStream.toByteArray());
```

This will work after you change your `tasksToExcel` methor to return the workbook instead of a `ByteArrayInputStream`

Comment: sorry I don't understand "FileResponse<Workbook> excel = reportService.getTaskOfMemberToTime(startDate, endDate);" what is this "FileResponse" in here?

Comment: Oh sorry, i forgot to add that class :)

Comment: the system don't understand "FileResponse"?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: sorry, wait me some minute!

Comment: system don't understand "@Data"

Comment: Added the constructor for you... if you still cannot solve your problem i'm out

Comment: It don't execute "excel.getFile().write(outputStream);"

Comment: And what is the error? Why it doesn't work? What is the expected result, and what you get instead? Could you please not just answer "it don't work" with that horrible English, and give us the details we need to answer?

Comment: sorry, I ran debug and it failed at "excel.getFile().write(outputStream);" because it can't write in excel file.

Comment: Well then something is wrong with your environment, because i have this code in a production system (Spring Boot 2.1.1)